# Почему interrupt() не изменил флаг?

Tags: java

Тестовый код:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start T1");
        Thread t = new T1();
        t.start();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) { }
        t.interrupt();
        System.out.println("Of T1");
    }

    public static class T1 extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                    System.out.println(this.isInterrupted());
                    System.out.println("T1");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вывод

```
 Start T1  
 Of T1  
 false -> почему так ?  
 T1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `sleep()` уже сам по себе "прерываемый". Если метод `sleep()` вызывается, когда установлено состояние прерывания (с помощью `interrupt()`), поток исполнения
не переходит в состояние ожидания. Вместо этого он очищает свое состояние (!) и генерирует исключение типа InterruptedException. Поэтому, все что вам нужно сделать, это еще раз руками установить флаг прерывания.
В вашем примере это будет не очень наглядно, но это общий принцип по отношению к методам типа `sleep()`, которые блокируют поток и кидаются исключениями `InterruptedException`. Вот таким должен быть ваш `run()` (можно без `this`):

```
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            this.interrupt();
            System.out.println(this.isInterrupted());
            System.out.println("T1");
        }
    }
```

Comment: То есть флаг изменился но произошло очищение и флаг снова был сброшен ?

Comment: Если б не было `sleep()`, мы б сами проверяли состояние флага. А так, это произошло в методе `sleep()`, который прервал свою "сонную работу", т.е., уже обработал наш запрос "прерваться". Он прервался, но как ему сообщить внешнему миру, что его прервали? С помощью выкидывания исключения. Но флаг он сбросил, т.к. уже его обработал. Многие почему-то думают, что `interrupt()` бросает `InterruptedException` и мы его можем перехватить с помощью `catch()`, но сами посмотрите в метод `interrupt()` - вы видите там `throw new InterruptedException`? Нет. Исключение в данном примере кидает метод `sleep()`

Comment: Откуда идет Exception я знал, а за нюанс со сбрасыванием флага БОЛЬШОЕ СПАСИБО!