# Почему isInterrupted() не меняет свое значение?

Tags: java

Решил проверить срабатывание isInterrupted() следующим кодом:

```
 public class Solution {
    public static volatile int countSeconds = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        RacingClock clock = new RacingClock();
        Thread.sleep(3500);
        System.out.println(clock.isInterrupted());
        clock.interrupt();
        System.out.println(clock.isInterrupted());
    }

    public static class RacingClock extends Thread {
        public RacingClock() {
            start();
        }

        public void run() {

        }
    }
}
```

И столкнулся с тем, что System.out.println(clock.isInterrupted()) после вызова
clock.interrupt() выводит false. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: тут недавно было обсуждение. Полистайте, буквально день-два назад.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/870101/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-interrupt-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому, что поток который вы пытаетесь прервать уже завершился

[`public void interrupt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt())

> Interrupting a thread that is not alive need not have any effect.

> Прерывание потока, который уже завершился не имеет никакого эффекта

[`public boolean isInterrupted()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted())

> A thread interruption ignored because a thread was not alive at the time of the interrupt will be reflected by this method returning false.

> Прерывание потока игнорируется, если поток был завершен к этому времени. Поэтому в этом случае метод возвращает false