# Вопрос по потокам в Java

Tags: java, многопоточность, исключения

Есть класс Clock, наследуемый от Thread с методом run().

```
public static class Clock extends Thread {
    private int seconds;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {               
            while (!currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                seconds++;
                System.out.println(seconds);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Конец отсчета.");
        }
    }
}
```

Метод main(), где запускаем поток, ждем 5 секунд, потом вызывается метод `clock.interrupt()`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Clock clock = new Clock();
        clock.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        clock.interrupt();
}
```

Вопрос:
Почему после вызова метода `clock.interrupt()` отрабатывает `catch`. Ведь по идее `!currentThread().isInterrupted()` должен стать `false`, и перестать работать цикл, следовательно поток(нить) `clock` должен закончить свою работу выполнив только то, что в `try`.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/870101/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-interrupt-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BB-%D1%84%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3/870175#870175 - тут подробный ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что метод [Thread.sleep(long)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)) выбрасывает исключение в случае если поток был прерван(был вызван метод [Thread.interrupt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt())). Про это можно почитать в [офф. документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html).

> InterruptedException - if any thread has interrupted the current thread. The interrupted status of the current thread is cleared when this exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

Условие `while (!currentThread().isInterrupted())` может отработать только в том случае, если вы вызовете `clock.interrupt()` в течение этих двух операций:

```
seconds++;
System.out.println(seconds);
```

Если же `clock.interrupt()` будет вызван в течение работы `Thread.sleep(1000);` (что вероятно почти на 100%) исключение будет выброшено мгновенно и перехвачено в `catch (InterruptedException e)`